# Query to rerturn unique set of fields in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I have alert records stored in an Elasticsearch 5.6 index. After performing a `_search?q=*` I get data back that looks like the following below:

```
  "hits": [ 
   {
      "_index": "alerts",
      "_type": "alert-mapping",
      "_id": "AWG0lW0jxQ7bOrwfOzFI",
      "_score": 1,
      "_source": {
        "events": [
          {
             "name": "walking",
          }
        ],
        "categoryID": "easy",
        "comments": "this is a comment",
        "active": true
      }
    },
    {
      "_index": "alerts",
      "_type": "alert-mapping",
      "_id": "AWds3wd43980wfOzFI",
      "_score": 1,
      "_source": {
        "events": [
          {
             "name": "running",
          }
        ],
        "categoryID": "difficult",
        "comments": "this is another comment",
        "active": false
     }
   }]
```

Based on the specification of the data the events array will only ever have one value. This may be updated in the future, but I can operate under this assumption for right now. What I am trying to do is create a query that will get all unique `events.name` values with their corresponding `categoryID`.

I have an example query that I thought would work, but instead it gives me back all the unique `events.name` values as well as all the unique `categoryID` values. My current query looks like this

```
GET alerts/_search
{
 "size":0,
 "aggs":{
    "alerts":{ 
        "terms":{ 
           "field":"events.name",
           "size":1 
         }
     },
     "categories":{
        "terms":{
           "field":"categoryID"
        }
     }
  }
}
```

This will return something that looks like this

```
"aggregations": {
"alerts": {
  "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
  "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
  "buckets": [
    {
      "key": "running",
      "doc_count": 225
    },
    {
      "key": "walking",
      "doc_count": 219
    }
  ]
},
"categroies": {
  "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
  "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
  "buckets": [
    {
      "key": "easy",
      "doc_count": 363
    },
    {
      "key": "difficult",
      "doc_count": 352
    }
  ]
}
```

}

What I really want is something that has both the `events.name` and `categoryID` grouped together in the returned results so I get all the `events.name` with their corresponding `categoryID`. Something that may look like this

```
"aggregations": {
"alerts": {
  "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
  "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
  "buckets": [
    {
      "key": "running",
      "categories": "difficult",
      "doc_count": 225
    },
    {
      "key": "walking",
      "categories": "easy",
      "doc_count": 219
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can nest the one in the other like this:

```
{
    "size": 0,
    "aggs": {
        "alerts": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "events.name",
                "size": 1
            },
            "aggs": {
                "categories": {
                    "terms": {
                        "field": "categoryID"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It won't be exactly the structure you want but it will give you, nested, all unique category ids per event name. I can't think of a way to do it that would result in your desired output.

Answer (score 0):

If you can change the mapping of the "events" field to type nested then you can use the reverse nested aggregation to get close to what you want.

```
POST /alerts/_search
{
 "query":{
    "match_all": {}
 },
 "aggs":{
    "events_name": {
        "nested": {
            "path": "events"
        },
        "aggs":{
            "events":{
                "terms": {
                    "field": "events.name"
                },
                "aggs":{
                    "category_ids":{
                        "reverse_nested":{},
                        "aggs":{
                            "cat_ids_per_event":{
                                "terms": {
                                    "field": "categoryID"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
 }
}
```

gets me this with dummy docs

```
"aggregations": {
    "events_name": {
        "doc_count": 9,
        "events": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [
                {
                    "key": "walking",
                    "doc_count": 5,
                    "category_ids": {
                        "doc_count": 5,
                        "cat_ids_per_event": {
                            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                            "buckets": [
                                {
                                    "key": "easy",
                                    "doc_count": 5
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "key": "running",
                    "doc_count": 4,
                    "category_ids": {
                        "doc_count": 4,
                        "cat_ids_per_event": {
                            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                            "buckets": [
                                {
                                    "key": "difficult",
                                    "doc_count": 4
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```